# Gazebo laser plug-in fails to publish scan results

Tags: mobile-robot, ros, navigation, simulation, gazebo

I have added hokuyo laser plug-in to mu urdf file. I successfully launched the robot in gazebo and done required changes to visualize it in rviz. I didn't get any error but the laser scan results are not published.

Fine my results below

Terminal while launching gazebo model in world

[image]

Result for `rostopic echo /scan`

[image]

I have also verified the tf of the model in rqt and its fine

Aslo find my urdf file below, can someone help me to fix this?

Link & joint:

```
<link name="hokuyo_link">
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.1 0.1 0.1"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <inertial>
      <mass value="1e-5" />
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <inertia ixx="1e-6" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="1e-6" iyz="0" izz="1e-6" />
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <joint name="hokuyo_joint" type="fixed">
    <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    <origin xyz="0 -0.055 0.2" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <parent link="Base_plate"/>
    <child link="hokuyo_link"/>
  </joint>
```

Controller:

```
<gazebo reference="hokuyo_link">
        <sensor type="gpu_ray" name="hokuyo">
          <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
          <visualize>false</visualize>
          <update_rate>40</update_rate>
          <ray>
            <scan>
              <horizontal>
                <samples>100</samples>
                <resolution>1</resolution>
                <min_angle>-1.570796</min_angle>
                <max_angle>1.570796</max_angle>
              </horizontal>
            </scan>
            <range>
              <min>0.10</min>
              <max>30.0</max>
              <resolution>0.01</resolution>
            </range>
          </ray>
          <plugin name="gpu_laser" filename="libgazebo_ros_gpu_laser.so">
            <topicName>/scan</topicName>
            <frameName>hokuyo_link</frameName>
          </plugin>
        </sensor>
      </gazebo>
```

Comment: From your `rostopic echo /scan` it looks like the results *are* published, except that they are not correct. Is it possible that the node that is supposed to talk with the hokuyo laser has trouble talking with the actual hardware?

Comment: Also, [it seems that](http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node) `urg_node` is going to replace `hokuyo_node`. Perhaps, give that a try?